# Changing DropDown size inside DropDownList [Flex, Spark Components]

Tags: flash, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I use flex SDK 4.5.1 and use spark component DropDownList.

I want to dynamically change the dropDown width(not the button of the dropdownList, just the dropdown itself, which is opened when the button is clicked)
to a fixed size (let's say - 140).

I managed to do so by coding this:

```
<s:DropDownList 
   id="cSelector"
   prompt=...
   dataProvider=...
   labelFunction="{ getOpLabel }"
   open="{adjustWidth()}"
   changing=...
   />
```

However, the dropdown isn't resized immediately after clicking on the dropDownList - I can see the resize process for a half of a second.
Can this be fixed or implemented differently? How?

In general, I prefer that the dropdown size will be adjusted by the widest item in the list, but this doesn't happen and it seems too complicated to fix it.

Note: The coding should be made in mxml file only.

Thanks in advance

### edit:

I also tried to do the following:

```
<s:DropDownList 
   id="cSelector"
   prompt=...
   dataProvider=...
   labelFunction="{ getOpLabel }"
   creationComplete="{handleOpenEvent()}"
   changing=...
   />
```

Then added:

```
protected function handleOpenEvent():void
{
    cSelector.addEventListener(DropDownEvent.OPEN, changeWidth);
}

protected function changeWidth(evt:Event):void
{
    cSelector.dropDown.width = 135;
}
```

But I still see the fast animation every time I open the dropdown. The first time is the longest one.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the width of the List inside the DropDownList you must add this in your open handler:

```
private function cSelector_openHandler(event:DropDownEvent):void
{
    cSelector.dropDown.width = 300;

}
```

While I was testing this code I noticed that the first time it does a very fast animation, subsequent times it just opens it at the desired width.

Comment: I tried this option. I wrote a function that calls cSelector.addEventListener(DropDownEvent.OPEN, cSelectorHandler_openHandler). This function is called by creationComplete. The implementation of cSelector_openHandler that I tried is quite the same as yours. But I still see the animation, not only in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the DropdownList using the following code and use this new CustomDropdownList and your issue will be solved. No need for setting width, it will take the widest item width.

```
package com {
import mx.collections.IList;

import spark.components.DropDownList;
import spark.components.PopUpAnchor;

public class CustomDropDownList extends DropDownList
{
    [SkinPart(popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth)]
    public var popUp:PopUpAnchor ;
    public function CustomDropDownList():void
    {
        super();
    }
    override protected function partAdded(partName:String,    instance:Object):void
    {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);
        if (partName == "popUp")
        {
            instance.popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth = false;

        }

    }
    public override function set dataProvider(value:IList):void
    {
        super.dataProvider = value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe this solution might work, but I wanted to solve it without extending DropDownList but write code in the mxml file only. Your suggestion requires writing a new class in AS file.